# Under which condition the roots of a quartic equation are in arithmetic progression?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the condition that the roots of $x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ will be in
> A.P.

I tried taking $(\alpha-3\beta),(\alpha-\beta),(\alpha+\beta),(\alpha+3\beta)$ as the roots then used the relation between roots and coefficients to get $\alpha=\frac{-a}{4}$, and $\beta=\sqrt\frac{3a^2-2b}{20}$. I think I made a mistake somewhere or this is the wrong approach because plugging in a root in the equation would make it really unwieldly.

Comment: Why did you pick those roots specifically? Does the AP have to have a difference term of $2d$ (is this the same $d$ as in the polynomial?) or could it be in any progression?

EDIT: actually on re-reading I think the $d$ there is meant to be $\beta$ right?

Comment: @Thomas its generally taken for AP with four terms similar to how you take (a-d),a and (a+d) for three terms.

Comment: Yes those shouldnt have been d but beta, and i took those roots because it makes the beta cancel out when you add the terms, but now the beta is complicated.

Comment: It doesn't seem that bad to just expand $(x - (\alpha - 3 \beta))(x - (\alpha - \beta))(x - (\alpha + \beta))(x - (\alpha + 3 \beta))$ and read off the coefficients no? It's a little tedious by hand but you get it in one shot